# If $A = \{(x,y) \mid x^2+y^2= 1 \}$ then $A$ is connected or not? Is it closed?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

My question is $A =\{(x,y) \mid x^2+y^2=1 \}$ is what kind of subset to $\Bbb R^2$

My guess is that they are not connected, but I do not know how to prove this. I have studied some topology only in the context of metric spaces, and I know that connectedness and compactness are topological properties, but I don't know if that applies here.

Comment: It's a circle!!

Comment: The curve is very symmetric, and has atleast $8$-fold symmetry, as $(\pm x, \pm y), (\mp x,\mp y), (\pm y, \pm x), (\mp y, \mp x)$ are solutions.

Comment: Notice that :
$$A = \left\{(\cos(t), \sin (t)) / t \in [0, 2\pi]\right\}$$
$A$ is the image of $[0,2\pi]$ witch is connected and compact by the continuous map $f(t)= (\cos(t), \sin (t))$ then $A$ is connected and compact.

Comment: The perimeter appears to be quite close to $2\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$